# No access to images

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony, shared-hosting

I installed Symfony2 on a shared server, the problem is that I can't view the images that I call in my template.

My pictures are in ~/myApplication/web/images directory.

I tried these methods in my twig template:

```
<img src="{{ asset('images/t.png') }}" alt="Twitter"/>
<img src="{{ asset('web/images/t.png') }}" alt="Twitter"/>
<img src="http://domain.fr/web/{{ asset('images/t.png') }}" alt="Twitter"/>
<img src="http://domain.fr/web/images/t.png" alt="Twitter"/>
```

But each time it is transcribed by `http://domain.fr/web/images/t.png` then I would have `http://domain.fr/web/images/t.png`.

I think it's a .htaccess problem but I don't what...

My .htaccess to the root of the Application:

```
SetEnv SHORT_OPEN_TAGS 0
SetEnv REGISTER_GLOBALS 0
SetEnv MAGIC_QUOTES 0
SetEnv SESSION_AUTOSTART 0
SetEnv ZEND_OPTIMIZER 1
SetEnv PHP_VER 5_3
AddType x-mapp-php5 .php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Someone may have an idea of ​​what this is?

I have no problem with CSS or JS files because I added this to my config:

```
framework:
    templating:
        assets_base_urls: http://domain.fr/web/
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Your images folder needs to be under web/bundles/yourbundle/images... Try this

Comment: The setence "But each time it is transcribed by http://domain.fr/web/images/t.png then I would have http://domain.fr/web/images/t.png." makes no sense. Can you try to explain it better?